# How to change the value display in the thumb of a range slider in ipyvuetify?

Tags: python, vuetify.js, ipywidgets

In the vuetify documentation the following [example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/sliders/#thumb)

```html
<v-slider
  v-model="slider"
  :thumb-size="24"
  thumb-label="always"
>
  <template v-slot:thumb-label="{ value }">
    {{ satisfactionEmojis[Math.min(Math.floor(value / 10), 9)] }}
  </template>
</v-slider>
```

And I try my best to adapt it to [`ipyvuetify`](https://ipyvuetify.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```py
toto = v.Slider(
    v_model=None,
    thumb_label = True,
    class_='mt-5',
    v_slots = [{
        'name': 'thumb_label',
        'variable': 'thumb.value',
        'children': 'toto'
    }]
)
toto
```

But my slider is till displaying numbers instead of "toto". what did I miss ? Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're calling the `v_slot` name as `thumb_label`, but the slot name is `thumb-label` indeed.

```
toto = v.Slider(
    v_model=None,
    thumb_label = True,
    class_='mt-5',
    v_slots = [{
        'name': 'thumb-label',
        'variable': 'thumb.value',
        'children': 'toto'
    }]
)
toto
```

Comment: ahh so the name of slots are not transform from `tutu-toto` to `tutu_toto` as the other keyword in ipyvuetify. Thanks, I'll see if it can be add in the documentation